# In wordpress upload images on new page but these are displaying on front-end

Tags: php, wordpress

[image]

[image]

I upload images on page but these images are not displaying on front-end.This is the code of my page.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>   
<section class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-hs-4 col-xs-12">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <article <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                <header>
                  <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            </header>
            <section>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
          <hr class="clearfix" />
                  <?php edit_post_link('Edit', '<p>', '</p>'); ?>
              </section>
                <hr class="clearfix" />
            </article>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</section>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-5 hidden-xs hidden-hs">
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `the_content()` only outputs the content but not the images. You will need to output the images doing some thing as,

```
  $image_attr = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium');

  // Now you are working with $image_attributes array and display whatever you want
```

Read more here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/

Comment: <?php the_content(); $image_attr = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium');?>                  I have added like that but same thing happening again. Images are not displaying on front-end